# pugixml error in nested class

Tags: c++, pugixml

I've got the following C++ code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <pugixml/pugixml.hpp>          //pugixml (version 1.6)

using namespace pugi;

class ClassA
{
    public:
        xml_document doc;

        void writeString(const char *str)
        {
            doc.append_child("randomString").append_child(node_pcdata).set_value(str);
        }
};

class ClassB
{
    private:
        class ClassB_Child
        {
            public:
                ClassA aInstance;
                long timestamp;

            public:
                ClassB_Child()
                {
                    timestamp = time(NULL);
                    aInstance.writeString("Hello world!");
                }
        };

    public:
        std::vector<ClassB_Child> vecBChild;

        ClassB()
        {
            vecBChild.push_back(ClassB_Child());
        }
};

int main()
{
    ClassB bInstance;

    return 0;
}
```

But every time I want to compile it (using MinGW g++ 4.8.1), just many errors are generated:

```
In file included from broken.cpp:3:0:
broken.cpp: In instantiation of 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = ClassB::ClassB_Child; _Alloc = std::allocator<ClassB::ClassB_Child>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ClassB::ClassB_Child*, std::vector<ClassB::ClassB_Child> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = ClassB::ClassB_Child*]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:913:28:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = ClassB::ClassB_Child; _Alloc = std::allocator<ClassB::ClassB_Child>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = ClassB::ClassB_Child]'
broken.cpp:40:38:   required from here
c:\mingw\include\pugixml\pugixml.hpp:941:3: error: 'pugi::xml_document::xml_document(const pugi::xml_document&)' is private
   xml_document(const xml_document&);
   ^
broken.cpp:7:7: error: within this context
 class ClassA
       ^
broken.cpp:21:9: note: synthesized method 'ClassA::ClassA(const ClassA&)' first required here 
   class ClassB_Child
         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\vector:69:0,
                 from broken.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:329:19: note: synthesized method 'ClassB::ClassB_Child::ClassB_Child(const ClassB::ClassB_Child&)' first required here 
    _Tp __x_copy = __x;
                   ^
In file included from broken.cpp:3:0:
c:\mingw\include\pugixml\pugixml.hpp:942:23: error: 'const pugi::xml_document& pugi::xml_document::operator=(const pugi::xml_document&)' is private
   const xml_document& operator=(const xml_document&);
                       ^
broken.cpp:7:7: error: within this context
 class ClassA
       ^
broken.cpp:21:9: note: synthesized method 'ClassA& ClassA::operator=(const ClassA&)' first required here 
   class ClassB_Child
         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\vector:69:0,
                 from broken.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:335:16: note: synthesized method 'ClassB::ClassB_Child& ClassB::ClassB_Child::operator=(const ClassB::ClassB_Child&)' first required here 
    *__position = __x_copy;
                ^
```

I also encountered, that all the errors disappear when I delete the `pugi::xml_document doc;` line (then the program compiles and runs fine). That means, the error has to be caused by pugixml. What do I have to change in my code to let the program compile properly?

Comment: why do you include pugixml/pugixml.cpp instead of pugixml/pugixml.hpp ?

Answer (score 0):

The first error explains your problem, albeit cryptically:

> pugixml.hpp: In member function 'ClassA::operator=(const ClassA&)':

The compiler is trying to synthesize a default assignment operator for you.  The default implementation will assign each member of the destination `ClassA` from the corresponding member in the source `ClassA`.  In this case, it will look *as if* you had

```
ClassA::operator=(const ClassA& other)
{
    doc = other.doc;
}
```

When it gets to trying to copy the `doc` member, it finds that it's not allowed to copy it:

> pugixml.hpp:942:23: error: 'const pugi::xml_document&
>   pugi::xml_document::operator=(const pugi::xml_document&)' is private

The inability to copy `doc` means that we can't copy a `ClassA`; in turn that means we can't copy a `ClassB_Child`, and that in its turn prevents declaration of a `std::vector` of `ClassB_Child`.

In order to solve your problem, you need to decide what you want to happen when you copy a class containing an `xml_document`.  If there's a means of providing the right kind of copy (a deep copy, probably), then create an appropriate assignment operator (and a corresponding copy constructor and probably a destructor - search for the "rule of three" or even "rule of five" or "rule of zero" on the Web).  Or perhaps you want to share a single XML document?